# GPS Chip manufacturers and infos on Android tablets

Tags: gps, gps-tracking, manufacturers

I'm working on some GPS tracking apps on Android tablets. We found out that depending on the type of phone / tablet we use, we can have results ranging from really accurate to really bad.

Those tests were conducted on the same track, with GPS only location - so I'm pretty sure the GPS chip quality is of great importance in those results differences.

Is there any way to access GPS chips manufacturers or infos depending on device models ? An app, command ... any means.

Comment: Hmm I forgot to add in my question that we're only working with android devices. That's why I posted here. Sorry for the oversight. Question edited.

Comment: Looks OK to me, I see no reason that an end user couldn't be interested in the model of their GPS chip.  I have removed the request for an off-site resource or programming solution since those are off-topic.  You could ask on [SO] about a way to use code to get this info -- just link to this question and point out that it differs in approach.

Comment: Thanks for letting me in. I finally found some informations. The thing is, I had trouble to find it because I didn't know nowadays the GPS module is embedded with cpu / gpu / ... whereas I was looking for standalone modules. 
Anyway I started a list myself (see answer).

Comment: I do a lot of work with GPS systems and antenna gain, placement and general design plays a huge part. Sleep / low power modes that can be changed in low-level software / firmware can also affect instantaneous accuracy so this generally might be a bit more complex than assuming one chipset is more accurate than another.

Comment: Thanks @PeterJ for your interest. Any luck you'd share some resources on the subject ? My list is just a starting point I guess, but I'm really new on the subject.

Comment: Indeed I already realized that some chips supposed to be rather good (embedded gps module with snapdragon 400 as an example) offered terrible results under some conditions (urban gps canyon) whereas some other mid quality offered good results.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find anything up to date over the internet.

Thing is : nowadays gps modules in mobile devices get embedded with other components such as gpu / cpu / wifi receiver / ....

So what you have to do is googling for "cpu details Galaxy Tab 10.1" for example, and then see what's included in this particular kind of chip.

Anyway I started a list for my own personal use, feel free to use / amend it : https://github.com/mhicauber/android-devices-gps-chip-manufacturers